# Getting SSLError with poetry add networkx cmd

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry

I am using poetry (1.0.10) to manage dependencies for a project.

I am currently getting an SSLError when running `poetry add networkx`

```
[SSLError]
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/networkx/json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

It seems I am only getting this error with `networkx`. Can someone help me figure this out? This is a key dependency for my project and I would like to use poetry if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the SSLError implies a problem with the SSL library, most likely OpenSSL. Can you verify that you have that installed?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have included that. version "OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019"

Answer (score 0):

This works for windows.

1. Connect to any https site with browser
2. Click on lock icon just to left of https://
3. View and save root certificate
4. Convert cert to .pem I used openssl that comes with git.

   `cd C:\Users\<my_username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin>`

   `./openssl x509 -in "C:\Users\<my_username>\<my_folder>\my_cert.cer" -out "C:\Users\<my_username>\<my_folder>\my_cert.pem"`
5. Open **my_cert.pem** in a notepad/notepad++. Copy the text
6. Locate your **cacert.pem**. In my case it was in the path below

   `C:\Users\<my_username>\.poetry\lib\poetry\_vendor\py3.9\certifi\cacert.pem`
7. Paste the text copied in step 5 to cacert.pem and save
8. Run `poetry add <package-name>`

Comment: What's the recipe to locating the `cacert.pem`?